# Set certain option of a select

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to update a row in table, so in edit mode I need to fetch the existing data and populate them in a card. Its fine with textboxes but trouble with selects. I cannot get the select to show the existing option fetched.

My mark up:-

```
    <select class="textbox-style4" data-ng-options="obj.text for obj in segment track by obj.value" data-ng-model="u_segment">
                                    </select>
```

here's how I am initializing the select: -

```
    $scope.segment = [ {
        "text" : "B2B",
        "value" : "0"
    }, {
        "text" : "B2C",
        "value" : "1"
    } ];
```

And here's how I am trying to set its value (tried two ways) :-
1)

```
    $scope.u_segment = selected.segment;
```

2)

```
    $scope.u_segment.value = selected.segment;
```

But it(select) still stays blank, though others (text fields) are populated.

Comment: What is the value of `selected.segment`? Is it an object with `text` and `value` properties?

Comment: @Lex No its a integer from DB, say 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting `obj`, so your `selected.segment` must be the entire object: `{"text" : "B2B", "value" : "0"}` (for example)

Here is a demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  var selected = {
    "segment": {
      "text": "B2C",
      "value": "1"
    }
  };

  $scope.segment = [{
    "text": "B2B",
    "value": "0"
  }, {
    "text": "B2C",
    "value": "1"
  }];
  
  $scope.u_segment = selected.segment;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <select class="textbox-style4" data-ng-options="obj.text for obj in segment track by obj.value" data-ng-model="u_segment">
    </select>
    {{u_segment}}

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

If you don't know the entire object, but only some property of it (like `value`), you need to search for it (in a loop):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  var selected = {
    "segment": "0"
  };

  $scope.segment = [{
    "text": "B2B",
    "value": "0"
  }, {
    "text": "B2C",
    "value": "1"
  }];
  
  for(var i=0; i<$scope.segment.length; i++){
    if($scope.segment[i].value == selected.segment){
      $scope.u_segment = $scope.segment[i];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <select class="textbox-style4" data-ng-options="obj.text for obj in segment track by obj.value" data-ng-model="u_segment">
    </select>
    {{u_segment}}

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```